# Условие: принимать только цифры в переменной

Tags: c#, переменные

Нужно, чтобы переменная принимала только цифры, а буквы и остальную нечисть посылала в лес.

Comment: А как вы тогда получите к ней доступ? Из леса? :-)

Comment: Почитайте какой-нибудь букварь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы вдруг не в курсе, то C# - статически типизированный язык с проверкой этих типов на этапе компиляции (за [некоторыми незначительными исключениями](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd264741.aspx)). Это значит, что в отличие от какого-нибудь php/JS вот такое не получится:

```
int someInt;
......
someInt = "some string";
```

Если же вам вдруг просто понадобились строки, которые не могут содержать ничего, кроме цифр, то можете написать что-то вроде

```
string someStr = SomeTextBox.Text;
int someInt;
if(Int32.TryParse(someStr, out someInt))
    <что-то там>
else
   throw new SomeException();
```

справедливости ради, в такой строке может быть еще и минус вначале, и, наверное, даже пробелы, точно не помню

либо проверить строку регулярным выражением, либо вообще написать какой-нибудь свой велосипед

Answer (score 1):

Объявите переменную типа `int` или `long`.

UPDATE: Если нужно использовать в текстбоксе то нужно проверять (и/или фильтровать) пользовательский ввод.
На ум сразу приходит след алгоритмы для игнорирования в строке НЕцифр (допустим что пользователь вводит текст в текст бокс `txtInput`):

1. регулярным выражением заменяем все НЕцифры в строке `txtInput.Text` на "пустоту"
2. в цикле пробегаем по всем символам строки `txtInput.Text` и те символы, которые являются цифрами, добавляем к новой строке.
3. обрабатывать нажатие кнопок клавиатуры и если нажата НЕцифра, то не добавлять символ в текстбокс

Comment: Если нужно что бы использовалось в текстбоксе, то как?
Другие варианты?

upd2, можно пример?

Comment: вы по-подробнее опишите что именно вам нужно. какова цель. опишите контекст задачи.